# How does AngularJS ui-router determine the root url of the application?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to host an SPA inside a CMS (Telerik Sitefinity). This app would be hosted in a 'widget' at an url like http://host/foo/bar/product/{root of SPA}

I'll be using ui-router to handle urls. What would url '/' resolve to if I configure the route state like below?

```
MyApp.config(function($stateProvider){
   var homeState = {
       name: 'home',
       url: '/',
       templateUrl: '/templates/home.html'
   }
   $stateProvider.state(homeState);
}
```

Would this route to http://host/ or http://host/foo/bar/product/ ?

The same question goes for the templateUrl too:
I need it to map to http://host/foo/bar/product/

Answer (score 0):

it will be http://host/foo/bar/product/ since the router will add to the end. This is both useful and can be a flaw ([see here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/50)). TemplateURL will also behave the same way so you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> ### Base href constraints
>
> The `$location` service is not able to function properly if the current URL is outside the URL given as the base href. This can have subtle confusing consequences...
>
> Consider a base href set as follows: `<base href="/base/">` (i.e. the application exists in the "folder" called `/base`). The URL `/base` is actually outside the application (it refers to the base file found in the root / folder).
>
> If you wish to be able to navigate to the application via a URL such as `/base` then you should ensure that your server is setup to redirect such requests to `/base/`.
>
> See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14018 for more information.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Using `$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#base-href-constraints)